# What is considered "The Word of the Lord" in the Episcopal Liturgy

Tags: anglicanism, episcopal

We finish the reading of scripture readings in the Episcopal church with the words:
"The Word of the Lord".

What does the Episcopal Church actually consider to be "The Word of the Lord?"

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). About your question, it's not clear to me exactly what you're asking. Are you asking what the Episcopal Church means when it uses the response, "The Word of the Lord" in its liturgy? If so, that could be answerable here. But if you're asking a general question about what the Word of the Lord is, that's far too broad for this site. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Please review the edit I made to your title.  If that isn't what you mean, please edit the question again to address Lee's points and any further clarification you can offer.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is defined for the Episcopal Church in particular,  and Anglicans more generally,  in the sixth of the [Thirty Nine Articles](http://anglicansonline.org/basics/thirty-nine_articles.html) [of Religion].

More particularly, the phrase "The Word of the Lord" is used in the service of Holy Communion, and in the offices of Morning and Evening Prayer to denote the conclusion of a reading from the Bible, the beginning of which was denoted by announcing the source of the reading, for example "A reading from the first letter of Paul to the Corinthians". The chapter and verse at which the reading begins may also be specified.